# VS Code run with debugging/run without debugging does not take latest change in the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have created a dotnet core solution and added two projects. I have updated the launch.json file and added both the projects. When I select a project and click Run with debugging/Run without debugging, it works fine first time. Then if I make any changes in the code for the project and hit run, new changes are not reflected.
Looks like it is not building the project before each run. I have to manually build the project to reflect the changes.
How do I make sure that the run with/without debug button first build the project before running it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I need to also update the tasks.json file and add all my projects there. By default, vscode only creates the launch.json file and tasks.json file with single project. If we have other projects in the solution we need to add them in the launch.json and tasks.json file.